# overflow:hidden is hiding everything on a webpage

Tags: css, slider

I'm trying to make a slider in a webpage, but overflow:hidden is hidding' everything instead just hide what comes out of the screen.
i need the images to be aligned and everything that comes out of the screen to be hidden.
My fiddle here:

```
HTML
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/geristengel/files/2013/05/i-ella-fashion-closet.jpg" class="imgs"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/2bff0e00-cbe8-49e5-85d4-7e4c052df449/f097abfe-d3d6-42c5-9768-11616bc985e2.jpg" class="imgs"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.lakecityphotography.com/design/images/fashion.jpg" class="imgs"/></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.thefashionhall.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/hnjh.jpg" class="imgs"/></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;

}

li{

    position:absolute;
}

.imgs{
    height:130px;
    width:180px;
    float:left;
}

div{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
```

Fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/mkv9x2fg/2/

Comment: You've added `overflow:hidden` to the div, so everything  sticking out of the div will be hidden. Everything works as expected. If that's not what you want and the images should be visible, then remove that rule.

Comment: Thanks, but that'd be more helpful if you tell me how should i make it so the overflow:hidden works correctly... i need the images to be aligned and everything that comes out of the screen to be hidden.

Comment: If "everything that comes out of the screen to be hidden" is your way of saying "No scrollbars" then apply the rule to `body` or give the div height. And if the images should be aligned then I have to ask how and to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the position absolute from the `li`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  white-space:nowrap;

} 

li {
   display:inline-block; 
  
  }


.imgs {
  height: 130px;
  width: 180px;


}
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/geristengel/files/2013/05/i-ella-fashion-closet.jpg" class="imgs" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/2bff0e00-cbe8-49e5-85d4-7e4c052df449/f097abfe-d3d6-42c5-9768-11616bc985e2.jpg" class="imgs" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.lakecityphotography.com/design/images/fashion.jpg" class="imgs" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.thefashionhall.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/hnjh.jpg" class="imgs" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: made the `li` inline-block and set the `div` to hide the overflow.

It's a little unclear what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a div width like width: 200px; heigth: auto: max-height: 500px;